# windows 8 & 7 on separate HDDs

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-8, multi-boot

I had windows 7 on my old hard drive then I bought a new one so I decided to install a win 8 on it . 
now I have them on separate disk and if I want to use one I should select that Hdd on setup boot menu . 
but there is a problem when I use windows 8 and decided to use win-7 It always perform checkdisk on startup , if I cancel that the drives that i used in win8 will no longer be functional. 
what should I do? is it something wrong? 
p.s : the drive letter of my win 8 is C in windows 8 itself but it's F in win 7

Comment: Your question is not clear.  The reason the chkdisk happens is because Windows 8 is modifying a Windows 7 disk.

Comment: is there any way that I could disable it ?

Comment: There is indeed a registry key value you can set so chdisk is not automatically ran.  That particular question has been asked more then once since I myself found the answer on this website.